# N Unit Test Debugger not stepping inside a static method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

My unit testing method is as follows

```
[Test]
public void TrackPublicationChangesOnCDSTest()
{
    //Arrange
    // objDiskDeliveryBO = new DiskDeliveryBO();            

    //Act
    var actualResult = objDiskDeliveryBO.TrackPublicationChangesOnCDS();

    //Assert 
    var expectedZipName = 0;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedZipName, actualResult);
}
```

The Actual method `TrackPublicationChangesOnCDS` in BO is as follows

```
public int TrackPublicationChangesOnCDS()
{

    var resultFlag = -1;

    try
    {

        string pubUpdateFileCDSPath = CommonCalls.PubUpdateFileCDSPath;
        string pubUpdateFileLocalPath = CommonCalls.PubUpdateFileLocalPath;


        if (File.Exists(pubUpdateFileCDSPath))
            File.Copy(pubUpdateFileCDSPath, pubUpdateFileLocalPath, true);

        if (File.Exists(pubUpdateFileLocalPath))
        {

            string[] pubRecords = File.ReadAllLines(pubUpdateFileLocalPath);

            var pubRecordsExceptToday = pubRecords.Where(p => !p.Trim().EndsWith(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"))).ToList();

            resultFlag = new DiskDeliveryDAO().TrackPublicationChangesOnCDS(pubRecordsExceptToday);

            File.WriteAllText(pubUpdateFileLocalPath, string.Empty);

            string[] pubRecordsCDS = File.ReadAllLines(pubUpdateFileCDSPath);
            var pubRecordsTodayCDS = pubRecordsCDS.Where(p => p.Trim().EndsWith(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"))).ToList();
            File.WriteAllLines(pubUpdateFileCDSPath, pubRecordsTodayCDS);

        }

        return resultFlag;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return -1;
    }

}
```

While debugging Debugger comes till 
`string pubUpdateFileCDSPath = CommonCalls.PubUpdateFileCDSPath;`

But `CommonCalls.PubUpdateFileCDSPath;` return empty string . It should return a file path . when the method is called directly it works fine . It doesn't work when it is called inside a unit testing method.

`CommonCalls.PubUpdateFileCDSPath` is a static property defined as below .

```
public static string PubUpdateFileCDSPath
{
    get { return GetXmlConfigValue("PubUpdateFileCDSPath"); }
}

public static string GetXmlConfigValue(string nodeName)
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(ConfigValuesXml);
    var node = xml.SelectSingleNode("JanesOfflineDeliveryService/" + nodeName);
    return node != null ? node.InnerText : string.Empty;
}
```

`Configvaluesxml` is a xml file path . Contents of the file is

```xml
<JanesOfflineDeliveryService> 
  <PubUpdateFileCDSPath>D:\OfflineDelivery\CDS\pub_update.txt</PubUpdateFileCDSPath>
  <PubUpdateFileLocalPath>D:\pub_update.txt</PubUpdateFileLocalPath>
</JanesOfflineDeliveryService>
```

Comment: What is `GetXmlConfigValue`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Updated the question

Comment: Now please provide content of `ConfigValuesXml` file

Comment: Seems like your tests actually using other xml file

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh, has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In your test scenario GetXmlConfigValue("PubUpdateFileCDSPath") does not exist, so string empty is returned. Thats why you should avoid static methods, because they are not mockable. A workaround could be to pass the path variables into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Using static dependencies make unit testing code in isolation difficult. invert the dependency by abstracting and injecting them into the dependent class.

```
public interface ICommonCalls {
    string PubUpdateFileCDSPath { get; }
    string PubUpdateFileLocalPath  { get; }
}
```

the implementation of the above interface would either wrap the your static calls or better yet just implement them.

The dependent class would be refactored to allow for the dependency inversion.

```
public class DiskDeliveryBO {
    private readonly ICommonCalls CommonCalls;


    public DiskDeliveryBO(ICommonCalls common) {
        this.CommonCalls = common;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity.
}
```

However the target method also has a lot of tight coupling to implementation concerns like the file system. That too should be abstracted and inverted out of the dependent class.